# How to correctly implement object inheritance in Scheme

Tags: scheme, closures, r6rs

As exercise, I'm trying to implement a small object oriented program, with 2 classes:

```
point1d: 1 attribute (x), getter and setter
point2d: inherits from point1d, add a new attribute (y) and its getter and setter
```

I have implemented each class as a closure. This is the code for the first one:

```
(define (point1d xx)
  (let ((x xx))
    (define (get-x)
      x)
    (define (set-x xx)
      (set! x xx))
    (lambda (f . args)
      (apply
       (case f
         ((get-x) get-x)
         ((set-x) set-x))
       args))))
```

and for the second:

```
(define (point2d xx yy)
  (let ((p1d (point1d xx))
        (y yy))
    (define (get-y)
      y)
    (define (set-y yy)
      (set! y yy))
    (lambda (f . args)
      (case f
        ((get-y) (get-y))
        ((set-y) (apply set-y args))
        (else (p1d f args))))))
```

I have some problem with the second definition; in the last line i try invoke parents method, but since `args` is a list it doesn't work.

What can I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the `point2d` lambda, you're trying to call `point1d`'s functions with

```
(p1d f (list arg1 arg2 ... argN))
```

while `point1d` expects the arguments to be:

```
(p1d f arg1 arg2 ... argN)
```

To solve this, `cons` f onto `args`, then `apply` that to `p1d`, like I have done in this fixed definition of `p1d`

```
(define (point2d xx yy)
  (let ((p1d (point1d xx))
        (y yy))
    (define (get-y)
      y)
    (define (set-y yy)
      (set! y yy))
    (lambda (f . args)
      (case f
        ((get-y) (get-y))
        ((set-y) (apply set-y args))
        (else (apply p1d (cons f args)))))))
```

Comment: Thank you. If you wish edit your answer, in the fourth line the last round bracket is wrong :) (i cannot edit becouse the edit must be at least 6 character long)